# Add new hyphenation rule to MS Word/OpenOffice

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice, libreoffice

I've noticed that the automatic hyphenation doesn't work optimally in MS Word. The problem is that it doesn't hyphenate some words that can be hyphenated. Can I somehow get it to hyphenate such words, I mean automatically?

Other office suites such as OpenOffice and LibreOffice are also susceptible to this behavior. I will be very grateful to you if you know the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can add which words you want to be automatically hyphenated by following the following steps. I am using Microsoft word 2013 as an example

- Open File in the top left corner of the screen
- Select Options
- Then on the options page go to the proofing tab
- Select Auto correct Options
- Add the words you wish to be automatically hyphenated

If you need any more information please see screenshot below or comment
[image]

Comment: You understand me incorrectly. By hyphenation I mean the algorithm that decides at which points a word can be broken over two lines with a hyphen. For example russian word _напряжением_ can be hyphenated as _на-пря-же-ни-ем_ but MS Word suggest _напря-же-ни-ем_ and I don't know how to get it do it correctly.

Comment: You could add an autocorrect rule for it i think, so replace напряжением  and напря-же-ни-ем with на-пря-же-ни-ем