# Hyphenate single word manually

Tags: microsoft-word

Writing the word *Einkommensteuer* in Word with automatic hyphenation turned on, it keeps inserting the hyphen as `Einkommens-teuer`, which is absolutely wrong, since the only allowed hyphens are `Ein-kom-men-steu-er`.

Selecting the word and clicking on *Silbentrennung* (Hyphenation) > *Silbentrennungsoptionen* (Hyphenation options) > *Manuell...* (Manual) brings up the wrong position:

[image]

But I cannot edit the content of this dialog, neither has inserting soft hyphens into the original word the desired effect of allowing hyphens only at their position.

How can I prevent Word from making *Einkommens-teuer* ("Income expensive") from *Einkommen-steuer* ("Income tax")?

Comment: You can turn off hyphenation or alter the MS *Wort* hyphenation dictionary: https://office-watch.com/2016/inside-words-language-tools/#Hyphenation

Comment: How can I alter it? Your link doesn't seem to contain information about that.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find out if Deutsch has a separate hyphenation file, but you can create an auto-correct rule that would change one word to another. See https://superuser.com/questions/977058/add-new-hyphenation-rule-to-ms-word-openoffice

Answer (score 0):

DrMoishe Pippik gave the right hint.

According to https://office-watch.com/2016/inside-words-language-tools/#Hyphenation, the dialouge only shows the possible hyphenation. "Einkommensteuer" is indeed a bug in the hyphenation dictionary of Word (I can reproduce).

A workaround would be, to insert a `-` to force the hyphenation at this point.
With `<Ctrl> -` you can add an invisible hyphen character, but it is not ensured, that word will break it at that position (it might).

Completely correcting the hyphenation would apparently require you to modify the dictionary, which is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: What effort would it be?

Comment: @Bowi I can't tell you. All I found about this topic was about custom dictionaries. Looking in my installation, it seems that the dictionary is a compiled binary file (LEX) (If this is the dictionary at all). I guess editing that requires decompilation and recompilation at least. But this is just wild guessing. I don't know for sure